# How to use backpropagation with a self-defined loss in pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch, backpropagation

I am trying to implement a Siamese network with a ranking loss between two images. If I define my own loss would I be able to do the backpropagation step as follows? When I run it sometimes it seems to me that it is giving the same results that the single network gives.

```
with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
    outputs1 = model(inputs1)
    outputs2 = model(inputs2)
    preds1 = outputs1;
    preds2 = outputs2;

    alpha = 0.02;
    w_r = torch.tensor(1).cuda(async=True);

    y_i, y_j, predy_i, predy_j = labels1,labels2,outputs1,outputs2;
    batchRankLoss =  torch.tensor([max(0,alpha - delta(y_i[i], y_j[i])*predy_i[i] - predy_j[i])) for i in range(batchSize)],dtype = torch.float)
    rankLossPrev = torch.mean(batchRankLoss)                                             
    rankLoss = Variable(rankLossPrev,requires_grad=True)

    loss1 = criterion(outputs1, labels1)
    loss2 = criterion(outputs2, labels2)


    #total loss = loss1 + loss2 + w_r*rankLoss
    totalLoss = torch.add(loss1,loss2)
    w_r = w_r.type(torch.LongTensor)
    rankLossPrev = rankLossPrev.type(torch.LongTensor)
    mult = torch.mul(w_r.type(torch.LongTensor),rankLossPrev).type(torch.FloatTensor)
    totalLoss = torch.add(totalLoss,mult.cuda(async = True));

     # backward + optimize only if in training phase
         if phase == 'train':
            totalLoss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            running_loss += totalLoss.item() * inputs1.size(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several lines where you generate new Tensors from a constructor or a cast to another data type. When you do this, you disconnect the chain of operations through which you'd like the `backwards()` command to differentiate.

This cast disconnects the graph because casting is non-differentiable:

```
w_r = w_r.type(torch.LongTensor)
```

Building a Tensor from a constructor will disconnect the graph:

```
batchRankLoss = torch.tensor([max(0,alpha - delta(y_i[i], y_j[i])*predy_i[i] - predy_j[i])) for i in range(batchSize)],dtype = torch.float)
```

From the docs, wrapping a Tensor in a Variable will set the grad_fn to None (also disconnecting the graph):

```
rankLoss = Variable(rankLossPrev,requires_grad=True)
```

Assuming that your `critereon` function is differentiable, then gradients are currently flowing backward only through `loss1` and `loss2`. Your other gradients will only flow as far as `mult` before they are stopped by a call to `type()`. This is consistent with your observation that your custom loss doesn't change the output of your neural network.

To allow gradients to flow backward through your custom loss, you'll have to code the same logic while avoiding `type()` casts and calculate `rankLoss` without using a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

```
   rank_loss = torch.mean([torch.max(0,alpha - delta(y_i[i], y_j[i])*predy_i[i] - predy_j[i])) for i in range(batchSize)], dim=0)
   w_r = 1.0
   loss1 = criterion(outputs1, labels1)
   loss2 = criterion(outputs2, labels2)
   total_loss = loss1 + loss2 + w_r  * rank_loss 
   if phase == 'train':
       total_loss .backward()
       optimizer.step()
```

You don't have to create a tensor over and over again. If you have different weights for each loss and weights are just constants, you can simply write:

```
total_loss = weight_1 * loss1 + weight_2 * loss2 + weight_3  * rank_loss
```

This is untrainable constant anyway, it does not make sense to create A variable and set requires_grad to True because weights are just constants.
Please upgrade to pytorch 0.4.1, in which you don't have to wrap everything with Variable